# Image preview for web sharing in Line chat

Tags: css, web

I make a website and I try to share it via Line chat. It seems that Line chat has a feature to display web preview like Facebook does. My question is, how to control which image and description that will be shown in Line chat? I know for Facebook but I never know in Line. I have tried googling around but I don't know the keyword for it. The google result is not what I expected.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are searching is using **HTML Meta Tags** on sites. Social Media such as facebook, twitter, etc. usually reads index.html's `<meta>` tags to provide a preview about the sites. You may learn more about meta tags [here](https://searchenginewatch.com/sew/how-to/2067564/how-to-use-html-meta-tags).